# How to write data into CSV file using only Core Java

Tags: java, file, csv, automation, soapui

I'm trying to implement automation script which should write address information (addrline1,line2,city,state,country,zipcode) into a CSV file. While googling, getting the samples using OpenCSV jar - CSVWriter which I don't need.

Can we achieve this only by using Core Java IO classes? If so, provide some samples.

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new csv file with a `BufferedWriter`
2. If your data is in a collection like `ArrayList<String>`, just loop over it and do a `bufferedWriter.write(line + System.lineSeparator());` for each item on your list

Something like this

```java
//CSV File Writer
public void writeToCSV(ArrayList<String> data) throws Exception {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("data.csv"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))){
        for(String line : data) {
            writer.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Often, customers want to open/edit CSV data using Excel, which assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding. If this is relevant, adapt StandardCharsets.UTF_8 above.